# Document windows explorer view - permissions and security issue

Tags: permissions, explorer-view

The windows explorer feature for opening sharepoint documents in sharepoint is great.But some users do go and open up the root site in explorer view and in this case they can see all site collections and subsites as folders etc..

Is it possible to block this somehow to stop user from browsing sites via windows explorer or some how disabling the feature?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](http://www.trustsharepoint.com/2013/08/disabling-windows-explorer-view-in.html) explains 4 methods in detail to disable 'Open with Explorer'. Below is a snippet of all the four methods

> Method #1: Remove `Use Remote Interfaces` permission for the users
>
> Method #2: Remove the “Open in Explorer” button all together from the SharePoint ribbon using [SharePoint solution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tejasr/2010/07/19/how-to-remove-open-with-windows-explorer-button-from-document-librarys-ribbon-menu/)
>
> Method #3: Modify the `DefaultTemplates.ascx` in the hive folder of `\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES`.
>
> Method #4: Disable WebDAV on the IIS Web Server

Comment: Thanks Naveen for the article . Something to think about